# Is there any way to call a method with h:commandButton without reloading page?

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

```
<h:commandButton value="A"   action="#{juegoService.ingresarPalabra('A')}">

</h:commandButton>
```

I'm using JSF 2.0, and I have a button like the above,
for each letter of the alphabet that call a method that load an image on the page, depending the word you press will load the corresponding image, but I need to call the method without reloading the page because I can only have loaded one image on the page, because when I click other the page reloads the Bean and the other image returns to the first state thats its not charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `f:ajax` and refresh container with image.

```
    <h:commandButton value="A with AJAX" id="button" action="#{juegoService.ingresarPalabra('A')}" >
      <f:ajax execute="@this" render="containerId" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: its other way aviable to use that isn't ajax?

Comment: Disa, you have choice: or full page reload, or ajax.